# DATE and TIME in MySQL (adding hour to date and selecting current date and time)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to do this:

```
INSERT INTO reservations
(user_id
,street_id
,reserved_from
,reserved_to
,reserved_date) 
VALUES 
($_SESSION['id']
, $id
, now()
, now()+1hour
, curdate()
)
```

Session id works, $id works, but help me for other 3 with time and date.
For the backend I am using PHP.
Thank you!

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `interval` syntax:

```
VALUES ($_SESSION['id'], $id, now(), now() + interval 1 hour, curdate())
```

Actually, you should be passing the first two columns in as *parameters*, not munging the query string.  So this should look like:

```
VALUES (?, ?, now(), now() + interval 1 hour, curdate())
```

Comment: @NikolaMilojic . . . "not working" is quite vague.  Do you get an error?  Do you get unexpected results?  What is really happening?  Do you realize that this is just the `VALUES()` clause and you still need `INSERT`?

Comment: Okey, so I made mistake I had ))) at the end insted of )), but still, in reserved_from i get current time, but in reserved_to I also got current time...

Comment: Okey mistake was again on my end, thanks for you help friend, you helped a lot !!!